# "This action could not be completed. Try again. (-22421)" while uploading a build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm facing with a `This action could not be completed. Try again. (-22421)
This action could not be completed. Try again. (-22421)` error for 2 days now while trying to upload a build to iTunes Connect.

I've read that its a bug in Apple's servers but now I'm skeptical about that claim because I don't think anyone else has a problem uploading a build and if it was Apple's problem that had been probably fixed it by now.

Anyone know why am I facing this error?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Application Loader to upload builds to iTunesConnect. At least it shows a correct and readable reason if upload fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try following solutions:

Use **Application Loader** to upload your app, as Xcode organizer can't upload file (rejects IPA) sometimes, without genuine reason and it's frequently occurring issue, with Xcode Organizer, that Apple could not resolve permanently.

**Solution for error code: 22421**

> - Apple app upload server is not working properly (not in
>     connection or lost connection during file upload). Just wait and try
>     again later (may be after a day).
> - Fluctuation in your network
>     connection, during file upload.
> - You may not have added privacy
>     statements in your info.plist file.

[Cocoa Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html): Here, is list of keys (with privacy statements) that you should consider to add in your info.plist file, if you have used that service in your application.

**Nowadays, you may also face, this error code: 90186 (with app loader)**

> - Outdated application loader can be reason of this error. Use [latest Xcode tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) and use application loader from Xcode Tool.
> - Incorrect/invalid provisioning profile, associated with your build. Ensure, your have used correct provisioning profile (A provisioning
>     profile with **Distribution/Production** mode is require. A *Development mode* provisioning profile won't allow your to upload app on store.)

You can find latest Application Loader Tool from latest Xcode Tool: Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader

[image]